# Concept of reduction and algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose that someone found an algorithm A for a NP problem (that is not NP-complete) that uses an algorithm B for PSPACE-complete or #P-complete problem during execution. (Remaining part of the algorithm takes polynomial time.)

Then suppose there is also an algorithm C for a NP problem that uses the polynomial-consuming part of the algorithm A. The rest of the algorithm C is actually an algorithm that solves NP-complete problems.

Then would this mean that PSPACE-complete or #P-complete collapse to NP-complete?

If so or if not, why would it be like that?

I am asking this question, because I seem to get confused during reading my computation textbook.

Edit: 
I was a bit confused as in (or more accurately scalar function) math, if g(x)=f(h(x)) and g(x)=f(q(x)), h(x) and q(x) must be virtually the same. So, my question was virtually the aforementioned. That was the parallel I was making between algorithm A and C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I see where your confusion arises. Hopefully ;).

Suppose you have a problem $\Pi \in NP$, and two algorithms $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ that both solve $\Pi$.

Assume that $\mathcal{A}$ uses algorithm $\mathcal{A'}$ as a sub-algorithm, where $\mathcal{A'}$ is acutally an algorithm for a $PSPACE$-complete problem.

Also assume that $\mathcal{B}$ is the same as $\mathcal{A}$, but instead of using $\mathcal{A'}$ as a sub-algorithm, it uses $\mathcal{B'}$, which is sufficient to solve $\Pi$, but not to solve the $PSPACE$-complete problem.

I think this is the situation you want to describe?

Now I think your confusion comes from assume that because a problem has two different algorithms, that the algorithms must have the same complexity - at least this is what I get from the analogy with the functions.

This isn't true, you can quite happily have an algorithm which solves a problem, but is actually far more powerful (i.e. it can solve a much bigger super-problem) and another algorithm that can only solve the smaller problem. These two algorithms don't really say anything about one another (at least without a lot more information).

To stretch the function analogy to its breaking point, the situation is more like $g(x) \leq f(x)+h(x)$ and $g(x) \leq f(x)+ q(x)$. Sort of. But not really.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell that you are confused from your question, but unfortunately I am not sure what's confusing you, maybe you can add more detail.

Now to answer you question, it is inconclusive given your description. The fact that you *can* solve a problem from one class by solving another problem from another class does not mean that you *need* do so.

The way reduction usually works (assuming you want to show that problem X is "hard" in some sense) is by showing that another problem Y can be solved by solving X plus some easy extra work, where Y is known to be "hard" in some sense.

Now back to your question. Suppose that we want to sort $n$ integers (a problem in NP). We do so by first solving a PSPACE problem, throw away the result, and use quick sort. This is effectively algorithm A that you described, and you can see why this does not say anything about the complexity classes involved.

Comment: I was a bit confused as in (or more accurately scalar function) math, if g(x)=f(h(x)) and g(x)=f(q(x)), h(x) and q(x) must be virtually the same. So, my question was virtually the aforementioned. That was the parallel I was making between algorithm A and C. So, math and computer science are different in this perspective, right?

Answer (score 1):

Luke [illustrates](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2700/98) one point of confusion; let me point out another one.

Algorithm $A$ for problem $P \in \mathsf{NP}$ uses algorithm $B$ for problem $Q \in \mathsf{PSPACE}\text{-complete}$. Is it possible that $A$ is "fast", that is it is not slower than $\mathsf{NP}$ allows for?

Yes! $Q$ may be harder than $P$, but maybe $A$ only ever calls $B$ with *easy* instances and thus stays within reasonable bounds! For example, $A$ may use $B$ on polynomially many instances of $Q$ of size at most $10$.